# decltype() variadic template base class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have the following code where I'm expecting `decltype()` to not work on `Derived` class to get `run()` base class method return-type, since the base class does not have a default constructor.

```
class Base
{
  public:
    int run() { return 1; }

  protected:
    Base(int){}
}; 

struct Derived : Base
{
  template <typename ...Args>
  Derived(Args... args) : Base{args...}
  {}
};

int main()
{
  decltype(Derived{}.run()) v {10}; // it works. Not expected since
                                    // Derived should not have default constructor
  std::cout << "value: " << v << std::endl;

  //decltype(Base{}.run()) v1 {10}; // does not work. Expected since 
                                    // Base does not have default constructor
  //std::cout << "value: " << v1 << std::endl;
}
```

I'm aware you can use `declval<>` to get member functions without going through constructors, but my question is why `decltype` works here. I tried to find in the C++ standard something relevant, but did not find anything. Also tried multiple compilers (gcc 5.2, 7.1 and clang 3.8) and have the same behavior.

Comment: Might it have to do with `decltype` being an unevaluated context and so it gets as far as seeing that `Derived` has a constructor that accepts no args but not as far as calling the initializer list?

Comment: Great answers from everyone! thank you so much for your time and C++ standard references! is what I was looking for in the post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Behold the magic of unevaluated contexts... and lying.

Actually trying to do something like:

```
Derived d;
```

will be a compile error. It's a compiler error because in the process of evaluating `Derived::Derived()` we have to invoke `Base::Base()`, which doesn't exist.

But that's a detail of the implementation of the constructor. In an evaluated context, we certainly need to know that. But in an *unevaluated* context, we don't need to go so far. If you examine `std::is_constructible<Derived>::value`, you'd see that is `true`! This is because you can instantiate that constructor with no arguments - because the implementation of that constructor is outside of the immediate context of that instantiation. This lie - that you *can* default-construct `Derived` - allows you to use `Derived{}` in this context, and the compiler will happily allow you to go on your merry way and see that `decltype(Derived{}.run())` is `int` (which also does not involve actually invoking `run`, so the body of that function is likewise irrelevant).

If you were honest in the `Derived` constructor:

```
template <typename ...Args,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<Base, Args&...>::value, int> = 0>
Derived(Args&... args) : Base(args...) { }
```

Then `decltype(Derived{}.run())` would fail to compile, because now `Derived{}` is ill-formed even in an unevaluated context.

It's good to avoid lying to the compiler.

Comment: I did try your solution before and it works as you mentioned. Still I was expecting to see an error (or at least warning) from compiler. `std::is_default_constructible<Derived>()` is `true`. Wouldn't this needs to be more clear in the standard (at least mention a line about it) when evaluating in compile time types?

Comment: @AdvSphere I think the most relevant Standard statement is [temp.inst]/4 "Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist."  A use in an unevaluated context like in `decltype(expr)` is not an odr-use and does not require a function definition to exist.

Comment: @AdvSphere "immediate context" isn't really [well-defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct-8).

Comment: @Barry, As I read today again your answer, it seems to be that you are saying because `std::is_constructible<Derived>::value` is `true` is the reason why `decltype(Derived{}.run())` works. But the implementation for `std::is_constructible<>` and `std::is_default_constructible<>` in gcc 4.9.4 uses `decltype()` precisely to know whether it has a default constructor? Please let me know if I misunderstand this part of your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AdvSphere `std::is_default_constructible<Derived>::value` being true a consequence, not the cause. The cause is that there's no constraint on the constructor template.

Answer (score 5):

When an expression inside `decltype` involves a function template, the compiler only looks at the template function's signature to determine whether or not the template could be instantiated if the expression were really in an evaluated context.  The actual definition of the function is not used at that point.

(In fact, this is why `std::declval` can be used inside `decltype` even though `std::declval` has no definition at all.)

Your template constructor has the same signature as though simply declared but not yet defined:

```
template <typename ...Args>
Derived(Args&... args);
```

While processing the `decltype`, the compiler just looks at that much information and decides `Derived{}` is a valid expression, an rvalue of type `Derived<>`.  The `: Base{args...}` part is part of the template definition and doesn't get used inside `decltype`.

If you want a compiler error there, you could use something like this to make your constructor more "SFINAE-friendly", which means information about whether or not a specialization of the template is actually valid gets put into the template signature.

```
template <typename ... Args, typename Enable =
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<Base, Args&...>::value>>
Derived( Args& ... args ) : Base{ args... }
{}
```

You might also want to modify the constructor to avoid "too perfect forwarding".  If you do `Derived x; Derived y{x};`, the template specialization `Derived(Derived&);` will be a better match than the implicit `Derived(const Derived&);`, and you'll end up trying to pass `x` to `Base{x}` rather than using the implicit copy constructor of `Derived`.